# what is the strategy about microphone selection on android?

Tags: android, audio, microphone

I have a android phone which has two internal microphones, one is primary and the other is secondary near the camera. The secondary is always chosen by my app whatever the AudioSource parameter sets( MIC, CAMCORDER, VOICE_CALL, VOICE_COMMUNICATION, etc. ).

Anyone knows the strategy about how android selects which mirophone to use?

Comment: Android doesn't really make that selection. It's implemented in the vendor-specific parts of the code that the platform vendor and OEM writes. Whether you pick one mic or the other would depend on several factors, like mic placement, the physical design of the handset, the types of mics used, etc. When I was working at Sony we would almost always have the `MIC` audio source pick the primary mic, and the `CAMCORDER` audio source pick the secondary mic. If you requested 2 channels for your recording and the handset had 2 mics we'd record from both of them.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. I think compatibility issue is the most defect of Android. I have to spend much effort to investigate and fix them( if possible ).